# Vue3, firestore, useFirestore: How to get notified when binding is ready?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3, pinia

I'm currently migrating my project from Vue2+Vuex to Vue3+pinia. The storage of choice is still firebase. To keep my local storage in sync with the remote firebase-database I want to setup a (one-way) binding. I plan to use `useFirestore` as [documented here](https://vueuse.org/firebase/useFirestore/#usage).

I wrapped in a pinia action:

```
async bindTodos () {
   this.todos = todos = useFirestore(collection(db, 'todos'));
}
```

with `this.todos` being defined in pinias `state`.

How can I maintain a boolean in the pinia state (i.e. `todosReady`) that get's updated when the todos were received the first time. Vuex/`bindFirestoreRef` used to return a promise. Or I am supposed to use `import {watch} from "vue"` and simply watch for changes in the returned `Ref`? Hope I'm on the right track!

Comment: Why do you need a Boolean ?. Why not just check for todos.length ?

Comment: @thezohaan `todos.length > 0` would be false if it has been received but there are none.